# How do I animate a clip's scale in FCPX?

Tags: video

I am trying to decrease the size of a clip by having it shrink over the span of a few seconds and disappear into the center of the frame. I couldn't find an answer elsewhere online but perhaps I didn't word it correctly in my search. Any suggestions/instructions would be appreciated. Thank you.

-A

Answer (score 1):

You need to use keyframes.

1. Select the clip.
2. Place the playhead where you want the animation to
   start.
3. In video inspector, go to Transform->Scale(All)
4. Adjust Scale to the starting scale size.
5. Click the add keyframe button on the right of the Scale parameter.
6. Repeat process for the ending scale keyframe.